# Cannot convert `List<List<int>>` into `string` using `JsonUtility.ToJson()` in c#

Tags: c#, json, list, unity-game-engine

I have 2 `List` in my `LocationData` class. The first list is: List. The second one is: List>. Whenever I try to convert it to JSON. The first List is being converted successfully, while the `List<List<int>>` is not.

```
//Location data class
public class LocationData{
        public List<int> answer_key;
        public List<List<int>> clues;
        public LocationData (List<int> p_answer_key, List<List<int>> p_clues){
            this.answer_key = p_answer_key;
            this.clues = p_clues;
        }
    }
```

The code below returns `JSON: {"answer_key":[5,4,0]}` only and not including the second List

```
//convert to json
string locationDataJSON = JsonUtility.ToJson (locationData);
Debug.Log ("JSON: "+locationDataJSON);
```

Comment: Can you check `locationData` content just before json serializes it? try to check if  `this.clues = p_clues;` is throwing an exception

Comment: Debug.Log ("LocationData: "+locationData);
returns "LocationData: Mapbox.Examples.LocationData"----

Debug.Log ("LocationData.AnwerKey: "+locationData.answer_key);
returns "LocationData.AnwerKey: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"----

Debug.Log ("LocationData.Clues: "+locationData.clues);
returns "LocationData.Clues: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]"

Comment: Do you have data in **clues** property??

Comment: @Clyde Dexter Santiago you need to debug your application with **breakpoints**, is `clues` empty or throwing an exception at being cast? you can catch exceptions with `try-catch` blocks

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Yes! I have data in `clues`

Comment: Then post how `locationData` is created. This will help people find your problem

Comment: I will assume that this is just something that the JsonUtility class doesn't handle. It is documented to only handle basic stuff so probably "List of list of" is out of scope.

Comment: Check this out https://imgur.com/a/ZY3Py

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen OMG!!!

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Can you help me to convert it to JSON?

Comment: `List<List<int>> clues` is not a simple type. Use `Newtonsoft` version for Unity that is linked from the duplicate answer. That should solve your issue.